# Parse strings with different formats of decimal numbers to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-parsing, currency-formatting

Is there in python a simple way to parse multiple different formats of possible decimal numbers into floats? Following formats could be used (usually amounts):

```
111 -> 111.00
111.00 -> 111.00
111,00 -> 111.00
11,111.00 -> 11111.00
11.111,00 -> 11111.00
11,111,111.00 -> 11111111.00
11.111.111,00 -> 11111111.00
111.111 -> 111111.00
111,111 -> 111111.00
111.111,00 -> 111111.00
111,111.00 -> 111111.00
```

At the moment I can only think of looking if there are different special characters ("," and ".") and then look which one is the decimal separator and so on. But that would be a lot of `if/else` I guess. I also tried `locale.atof` but the problem is, that I don't know which format the string is. I'm wondering if there is an easier and cleaner way.

Comment: How about 111.111 and 111.111,00? Are these the same values? Or is the last '.' or ',' always the separator between integer and decimal part?

Comment: That's a good point. I would expect it to be the same numbers. I add it to the examples in the question.

Comment: In that case you have the problem that you don't know if there is a decimal part or that it is an integer. Unless you add more restriction to the input format.

Comment: So, with the edit done, it seems like the general rule is: If the last "group" of integers are 2 or less, then they are in the float-value. Otherwise, all integers are whole numbers.

Comment: I have no control over the input format. So like @HampusLarsson explained, that's what I would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the most efficient way to do it, but using regular-expression, we can split the variable into their different parts, and count the "last one" of them, to decide how to do the translation.

```
import re

values = """111
111.00
111,00
11,111.00
11.111,00
11,111,111.00
11.111.111,00
111.111
111,111
111.111,00
111,111.00"""

values = [i for i in values.split("\n")]
for value in values:
    value = re.split(r"\.|,", value.strip())
    if len(value[-1]) <=2 and len(value) > 1:
        newVal = float("".join(value[:-1]) + "." + value[-1])
    else:
        newVal =float("".join(value))
    print(newVal)
```

Output:

```
111.0
111.0
111.0
11111.0
11111.0
11111111.0
11111111.0
111111.0
111111.0
111111.0
111111.0
```

---

EDIT:
I didn't sanitize my inputs, the first version included some whitespace, throwing the translation into a loop.

Comment: That looks great. The few tests I just made with that code look promising.

Comment: Great! Keep in mind, that if the float-value of the input is ever more digits than 2, then it will not translate correctly.